# How to deal with dependent variable that has different ranges for different groups?

Tags: modeling, panel-data, finance

I have loan-level data on peer-to-peer (p2p) loans. I am studying how the number of bank branches in the borrower's county affect his willingness to pay for p2p loans. My LHS variable is the borrower's stated maximum interest rate, i.e., his willingness to pay. My RHS variable is the number of bank branches in the borrower's county. The problem is, different states have different interest rate caps. This clearly affects my LHS variable. My question is, how do I control for this so that I can use observations from every state.

Comment: Have you already considered censored regression models, like the `tobit` model? Censored least absolute deviations estimator (CLAD) is another option, one that makes comparatively weaker assumptions.

Comment: How do I implement a tobit regression (say in stata) when observations from different states have different upper bounds?

Comment: There are extensions, like `intreg`, where the upper bounds can be observation-specific, so state-specific would be possible too.